# Call to undefined method addFieldToFilter() in magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, model, resource-model

I have a model,resource model,collection file shown below.

app/code/Magge/Custom/Model/Categrory.php

```
namespace Magge\Custom\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Categrory extends AbstractModel
{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('Magge\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Categrory');
    }
}
```

app/code/Magge/Custom/Model/ResourceModel/Categrory.php

```
namespace Magge\Custom\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Categrory extends AbstractDb
{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('customer_products', 'customproduct_id');
}
}
```

app/code/Magge/Custom/Model/ResourceModel/Categrory/Collection.php

```
namespace Magge\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Categrory;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('Magge\Custom\Model\Categrory', 'Morello\Customproducts\Model\ResourceModel\Categrory');
}

}
```

I have a another module named CustomPriceApi within which I have a price.php file in `Model` .From this file I am try use the factory class but got the error.

```
namespace Insigma\CustomPriceApi\Model;

class Price implements PriceInterface {

public function __construct(
\Magge\Custom\Model\CategoryFactory $factoryCategory,
.....
)
{
$this->factoryCategory   = $factoryCategory;
}
```

Within its public method I use

```
$category = $this->factoryCategory->create()->addFieldToFilter('price_id',array('eq' => $priceId))->getData();
```

And I get  error.I tried using addAttributetoFilter() but still get undefined method.Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is directly inject the collection factory related to your model into the constructor of the `Price` class.

So, in the constructor of `Insigma\CustomPriceApi\Model\Price`, inject the `Magge\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Categrory\CollectionFactory` factory. Collection classes are what have the `addFieldToFilter` and other search related methods for retrieving results from a collection.

You will still need to call the `create()` method on the CollectionFactory before using and calling filtering methods to get results.

You can technically call `getCollection()` from a model, but it is a violation of **Separation Of Concerns** and considered a deprecated approach since a model should only be concerned with the data it represents.

Comment: Tnx, this was quite informative, I was missing the create() part.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
$category = $this->factoryCategory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('price_id',array('eq' => $priceId))->getData();
```

Comment: Hi @Rutvee,I use it.Each time I use getCollection() I get varnish cache error.

Comment: please check after clearing your generated folder and cache

Answer (score 0):

You did the mistake at collection class:

```
$this->_init('Magge\Custom\Model\Categrory', 'Morello\Customproducts\Model\ResourceModel\Categrory');
```

You have put wrong resource class  at here

it should be

`Magge\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\Category`

from

`'Morello\Customproducts\Model\ResourceModel\Categrory'`